How to make a simple edit of a field value using pyshp
I'd like to change the values in a shapefile (dbf file only, not any of the geometry). That would seem to be most common usage of pyshp to me, yet I am mystified as to how to code it.
Imagine I start with this point shapefile and I want to change the colors in the "Text" field:
ArcMap shapefile attributes
This is the code that I have:
import shapefile

myfile = r"J:\Test_Shapefile.shp"
outfile = r"J:\Test_Out_Shapefile.shp"

# read records only
records = shapefile.Reader(myfile).records()

# edit record values
records[0][4] = 'Green'
records[1][4] = 'Blue'
records[2][4] = 'Red'
records[3][4] = 'Yellow'

# read full shapefile for structure
r = shapefile.Reader(myfile)

# define output shapefile (dbf only; geometry shp/shx is not edited so can be reused)
w = shapefile.Writer(dbf=outfile)

# set up fields structure from original shapefile
w.fields = list(r.fields)

# write edited values
for record in records:
    w.record(record) # << problem

# close output file
w.close()


The problem arises at the writing step. I have tried many ways of converting the record to a string or list but always some sort of AttributeError or TypeError. I'm sure there's a simple answer because such a basic operation... or maybe not? Maybe I should give up on pyshp altogether and try another shapefile reader/writer?
EDIT: OK, I had more success with this set-up (no errors) but the shapefile is now empty (yes, I overwrote the original .dbf this time, so all other associated shapefiles are present (shp, shx, prj, etc)).
import shapefile

myfile = r"J:\Test_Shapefile.shp"
outfile = r"J:\Test_Shapefile.shp"

# read shapefile
r = shapefile.Reader(myfile)

# define output shapefile (dbf only; geometry shp/shx is not edited so can be reused)
w = shapefile.Writer(dbf=outfile)

# set up fields structure from original shapefile
w.fields = list(r.fields)

# transfer new values
for rec in r.iterRecords():
    if rec[1] == 1:
        rec[4] = 'Green'
    if rec[1] == 2:
        rec[4] = 'Blue'
    if rec[1] == 3:
        rec[4] = 'Red'
    if rec[1] == 4:
        rec[4] = 'Yellow'
    w.record(*rec)

# close output file
w.close()


If you don't want to edit in-place as your initial example showed, I'd recommend using geopandas.
You can read a shapefile (or most other GIS file formats) with one line of code, edit the data using the very common pandas syntax as it is a pandas extension, and write it again in another line of code.
import geopandas as gpd

myfile = r"J:\Test_Shapefile.shp"
outfile = r"J:\Test_Out_Shapefile.shp"

gdf = gpd.read_file(myfile)

# Update the values of column index 4 like the sample code. If you just replace 
# `iloc` by `loc` you can use the column name instead of 4 which is probably cleaner.
gdf.iloc[0, 4] = "Green"
gdf.iloc[1, 4] = "Blue"
gdf.iloc[2, 4] = "Red"
gdf.iloc[3, 4] = "Yellow"

gdf.to_file(outfile)


Thank you for the fast reply, Pieter. Yes, it works straight out of the box as you typed up. I already invested a lot of time into pyshp in the past so wanted to continue with it, but that's the sunk cost fallacy. I'll start using geopandas from now on. It's more functional anyway from what I've read. Thanks again for your help and advice.
